# ConstraintLayout ignoring constraints

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a `ConstraintLayout` with a few elements and two buttons.

I am trying to put the buttons at the bottom by using top and bottom constraints and using the bias property to get the bottom/left/right alignment.

Everything shows up correctly in the editor (`Android studio 2.2 P3`) but when I run the app, nothing displays correctly.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Heres the relevant sections of the `layout XML`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout      
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp">

   ...snip...

    <Button
        android:text="Reset"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Apply"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/profile_apply_button"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: View in editor]

[image: View when running]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get around the issue by using vertical and horizontal guidelines set to left/bottom/right edges, and my controls correctly align to those guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this was loaded from a fragment? if so, instead of using things like:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
```

you should use:

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
```

(available since ConstraintLayout alpha 5). It's best as well to update to the latest releases of Android Studio (e.g. [2.2 beta](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio22betaavailable)), the editor will do the work for you to replace those references.